# Fellowships/Awards section in graduate application include scholarships

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding

I am applying to Physics PhD programs at various institutions. Most applications have a section to include Fellowships and Awards. Does this only refer to funding for graduate studies (such as Fullbright or NSF GRFP) or should this include scholarships received for my undergraduate studies?

Answer (score 1):

You can include fellowships, awards, and scholarships of any sort at any point that are relevant to your academic pursuits.

If you have funding for *future* graduate study already secured (that is, for the work you will do in the program you are applying for), you can list that here, too, but I'd also be sure to draw attention to it elsewhere in your application as this would be very important information (and something that would be very unusual for most applicants, but may be more common with programs funded by specific countries).